# Crear un .jar con las librerías incluídas NetBeans

Tags: java, javafx, compilar, jar, librería

estoy intentando compilar el proyecto para que me incluya todas las librerías en un sólo archivo .jar.

He intentado lo siguiente en el build.xml (entre etiquetas target):

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="nombreDeMiApp"/>

    <property name="store.dir" value="dist"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>

    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
    <delete dir="${store.dir}/lib"/>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/README.TXT"/>
</target>
```

Sin embargo, mi aplicación es FXML, por lo que al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3479: The following error occurred while executing this line:

dist\lib does not exist

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un solo .jar con las librerías incluidas en NetBeans FXML, usa ésto en el build.xml:

```
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
    <fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}" nativeBundles="all" outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
        <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
            <fx:resources>
                <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
            </fx:resources>
        <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
    </fx:deploy>
</target>
```